# Redirect After Certain Amount of Time ONLY It Traffic Coming From Particular Source

Tags: redirect

So, I have an ecommerce site, we sell one product only.  We have a high conversion rate via Google Product Listing....however, their policy states that they can only link your ad DIRECTLY to the product page...for obvious reasons...but my company is an exception as we only provide one product..and our homepage is actually a better resource for the product, so we would love to find a way to get more traffic from the product listing campaigns back to the homepage...as we have a high bounce rate with good traffic, despite the strong conversion rate (we think it could be much higher)

I want to know if there's a way to redirect people from the product page back to our homepage after a certain amount of time.....but ONLY for traffic coming from the google PLA campaign.

Any suggestions would be helpful (aside from "make your product page better")

Thanks guys!
Gary

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like that:

```
if(document.referrer.indexOf("http:urlYouwantToRedirect.com/path") > -1){
    document.location.href = "http:redirection.com";
}
```